# Is there a compiler warning that will catch code after a function returns?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

given this function:

```
int doThings() {
    int x = 1;
    return x;
    x + 1;
    cout << "x: " << x << '\n';
}
```

Is there a compiler warning flag (g++ or clang++) that can catch the fact the code after return won't be run?

UPDATE:

Running clang++ with -Wunreachable-code did the trick

Comment: Usually there's the 'unreachable code detected' warning that should be issued. Don't you get it when compiling the above sample?

Comment: See [this posting](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-05/msg00360.html) on the gcc mailing list. It seems that `Wunreachable-code` has been removed since gcc 4.5.

Comment: I suspect that most compilers will warn about this if optimization is turned on.  Without optimization, most compilers will process a statement at a time, and so not be able to detect it.

Comment: James, compiling with -O2 didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gcc` compiler (up to 4.4) had a `-Wunreachable-code` option which should catch this.

This wasn't part of the `-Wall` group since you're more likely to have unreachable code during the development process, the time when you're most likely to be using `-Wall`.

It was removed as of 4.5 due to inconsistencies with the optimiser. By removed, I mean the compiler still accepts the flag but doesn't act on it. I believe Clang still includes that option, since it likes to be compatible with gcc.

Comment: If the issues were not just about false positives or missed detections and instead enabling a warning can actually influence code generation then the picture looks somewhat scary...

Answer (score 1):

Clang provides `-Wunreachable-code`, which will warn for this code ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1d0b924022769e3)).

GCC also provides this option, but it has been silently disabled since gcc 4.5.

`x + 1;` does nothing, regardless of whether or not it is ever run. This is caught by `-Wunused-value`.